# How can i check if the person liked facebook page or not in social plugins of facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am Using the facebook social plugins of likebox get it from [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Here how can i check if the facebook user is liked or not. I using iframe of facebook from social plugin. I tried to search in google [Facebook Check whether user has liked the page or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053745/facebook-check-whether-user-has-liked-the-page-or-not)

I also checked the javascript sdk for facebook [Facebook how to check if user has liked page and show content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246449/facebook-how-to-check-if-user-has-liked-page-and-show-content)

How can i do this for social plugins is any other way to check if the user has liked or not. How can i do this any suggestion would be great.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http://facebook.com/cocacola&amp;width=292&amp;height=290&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/Yanep/2/ that i tried

Thanks in Advance. I struggle for a day to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a way to check if a user likes or not a page? You can use the facebook graph api. here [try the facebook graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20where%20uid%3Dme%28%29%0A) and check the [fql reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).
You can extract the pages which are liked by an user and compare the results with the id of a page or you can select the id from the pages liked (`select page_id FROM page_fan where uid=me() and page_id='{page_id}'`)and, if the results will be empty, the page is not liked by the user.